# exporting data to xls

Tags: javascript, export, xls

I want to generate an excel from ui which will have all the data that is displayed on the screen . I am passing all the parameters as hidden through my javascript but that does not work if parameters are more than 10,000. Is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: How are you passing those parameters passed to the server? Can you show some sample code? Are you using a GET or POST request?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your problem ? You already have a backend that generates xls documents, isn't it ? Your only problem is that you can't send as much parameters as you would. Is this your problem ?